# Persisting form data after login/sign UP through devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am working on a rails app which uses devise for authentication. In my app there is a query form, but only a signed in user can fill the query form. 
If the user is not signed in, he can fill the data in the from, but as he clicks submit I want him to be redirected to the sign_up page, there he can sign_up or sign_in. Once he does that I want him to be redirected back to the previous page and his form data be restored so that he doesn't need to fill the form again.

So far I am able to implement the redirecting back to previous page part but I am unable to persist the form data

Code of my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  #after_filter :store_location

    after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
  return unless request.get? 
  if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
      request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&
      !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
  end
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  request.referrer
end

end
```

Can anyone please help me in persisting the form data so that he doesn't need to fill the form again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the create action of your form controller, you must check if the user is logged in or not.

Basically, what you want is, if the user is not connected, store the `params` received into a session variable and redirect the user to the registration form and use the Devise built in function `after_sign_in_path_for` to redirect him to your form if Rails detects a session variable.

It should look something like that:

```
# forms_controller.rb
class FormsController < ApplicationController

# Make sure not to filter 'create' as we'll be handling that with our redirect
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create]

...

def create
  # Check to see if the user is registered/logged in
  if current_user.nil?
     # Store the form data in the session so we can retrieve it after login
     session[:form_data] = params
     # Redirect the user to register/login
     redirect_to new_user_registration_path    

  else
    # If the user is already logged in, proceed as normal
    ...

  end
end


# application_controller.rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

  # redirect to the form if there is a form_data in the session
  if session[:form_data].present?

    #redirect to your form path

  else
    #if there is not temp list in the session proceed as normal
    super
  end

end
```

To repopulate your form, in your controller action 'new', you could do something like:

```
if session[:form_data]
  @my_form = Form.new(session[:form_data])
  session[:form_data] = nil
  @my_form.valid? # run validations to populate the errors[]
else
  @my_form = Form.new
end
```

For more information about it, take a look at [this tutorial](http://blog.justinthiele.com/retaining-form-data-through-a-login-process-a/).

Comment: I get this error while implementing the same Error: unknown attribute 'utf8'. Resolved the issue. Basically the data was nested inside session[:form_data]["key name"]